# Error when using to_datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a data frame like this:

```
         Date  Quote-Spread
0  2013-11-17      0.010000
1  2013-12-10      0.020000
2  2013-12-11      0.013333
3  2014-06-01      0.050000
4  2014-06-23      0.050000
```

When i use this code i raise an error:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'] ,format ="%Y%m%d")

ValueError: time data '2013-11-17' does not match format '%Y%m%d' (match)
```

how can i correct this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) only:

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
print (df1['Date'])
0   2013-11-17
1   2013-12-10
2   2013-12-11
3   2014-06-01
4   2014-06-23
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Or if want specify format add `-`, because `%Y%m%d` match `YYMMDD` and your format is `YY-MM-DD`:

```
pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'], format ="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 2):

to_datetime is the way to go. It is the fastest too if compared to the alternative of using list comprehension or apply.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# Create dataset
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(Date=['2013-11-17','2013-12-10']*10000))
```

Alt1, list comprehension:

```
df1.Date = [datetime.datetime.strptime(i,"%Y-%m-%d") for i in df1.Date.values]
```

Alt2, apply:

```
df1.Date = df1.Date.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x,"%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Alt3, to_datetime:

```
df1.Date = pd.to_datetime(df1.Date)
```

**Timings**

```
1 loop, best of 3: 744 ms per loop #1
1 loop, best of 3: 793 ms per loop #2 
100 loops, best of 3: 18.5 ms per loop #3
```

Comment: Try add timings for `pd.DataFrame(dict(Date=['2013-11-17','2013-12-10'] * 10000))` thanks.